# Mongo start problems after upgrading to Mac BIgSur - (Failed to unlink socket file)

Tags: mongodb, macos, macos-big-sur

I've upgraded my MacOs to BigSur. Since then I was unable to start my already installed Mongo.

So, I've decided to uninstall my 4.2 Mongo version and go to version 4.4:

```
$ brew uninstall mongodb
$ brew install mongodb-community@4.4
```

All fine.

When running I had to upgrade to XCode 12 (done using AppStore app).

All fine.

Now it is time to start Mongo:

```
$ brew services start mongodb-community@4.4
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-30T10:53:39.834-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-30T10:53:39.837-03:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-30T10:53:39.837-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-30T10:53:39.838-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":9309,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/usr/local/var/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"MBook1.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-30T10:53:39.838-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.5","gitVersion":"ff5cb77101b052fa02da43b8538093486cf9b3f7","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-30T10:53:39.838-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"20.4.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-30T10:53:39.838-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/usr/local/var/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-30T10:53:39.839-03:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-30T10:53:39.839-03:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":919}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-30T10:53:39.839-03:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Seems that "Failed to unlink socket file" is the problem. I suspect this is related to BigSur security features, but I can't find out how to solve it. Tried to look and "Security Preferences" on System Preferences but I can't find Mongo issues.

Comment: What are the permissions on /tmp and /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock?

Comment: `lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11  1 Jan  2020 tmp -> private/tm` and `srwx------  1 root  wheel  0  3 Mai 15:59 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a permissions issue.

The socket file noted in the error message is owned by root, with no permissions for other users.  The log specifically calls out permission denied, indicating the  account that brew is using to start the service is not root.

```
"msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}
```

To fix this, delete the file manually with `sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` and then try to start mongod.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I delete it and just after it is immediately created again with same permissions... Ideas of what may be causing it?

Comment: A mongod process already running as root? Find out what is listening on port 27017.

Comment: No mongod process running... `lsof -i -P | grep 27017` returns nothing...

Comment: Need to `sudo` that lsof command to see processes not owned by your user.

Comment: Same result with `sudo`. `ps aux | grep mongo` also does not show any mongo process running...

Comment: If you delete that file and it just comes back, there is something creating it.  If there is a process not named mongod that is creating a socket named mongod, there is something really strange going on.

Comment: Sure something strange is happening. I have the same mac running for more than 3 years and just after I've upgraded the SO mongo stopped working.... and that's why I'm here at SO asking for help...